# Database for 5-dimensional data?

Tags: sql, database, large-data, nosql

I commonly deal with data-sets that have well over 5 billion data points in a 3D grid over time. Each data point has a certain value, which needs to be visualised. So it's a 5-dimensional data-set. Lets say the data for each point looks like (x, y, z, time, value)

1. I need to run arbitrary queries against these data-sets where for example the value is between a certain range, or below a certain value.
2. I need to run queries where I need all data for a specific z value

These are the most common queries that I would need to run against this data-set. I have tried the likes of MySQL and MongoDB and created indices for those values, but the resource requirements are quite extreme with long query-runtime. I ended up writing my own file-format to at least store the data for relative easy retrieval. This approach makes it difficult to find data without having to read/scan the entire data-set.

I have looked at the likes of Hadoop and Hive, but the queries are not designed to be run in real-time. In terms of data size it seems a better fit though.

What would be the best method to index such larger amounts of data efficiently? Is a custom indexing system the best approach or to slice the data into smaller chunks and device a specific way of indexing (which way though?). the goal is to be able to run queries against the data and have the results returned in under 0.5 seconds. My best was 5 seconds by running the entire DB on a huge RAM drive.

Any comments and suggestions are welcome.

EDIT:
the data for all x, y, z, time and value are all FLOAT

Comment: How different are the data? May be it's reasonable to create multiple tables e.g. table_z1, table_z2... table_zN. Or store values range in a separate table with index and have a foreign key to the value_container_table. Please update your question adding column types and may be a bit more business logic information

Comment: what about google's BigTable http://research.google.com/archive/bigtable.html

Comment: i suppose there can only be two of three constraints met in a system. those are Speed, Consistency and High Data Volume. Perhaps a custom solution with the bulk of data being stored in a solid DB that can be easily queried and is fast if the data set is small on each node. and then have a caching layer like Redis on top in which certain customised abstraction or filters are stored.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the hardware you have available, but regardless of that and considering the type and the amount of data you are dealing with, I definitely suggest a clustered solution.

As you already mentioned, Hadoop is not a good fit because it is primarily a batch processing tool.

Have a look at [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/) and see if it solves your problem. I feel like a column-store rdbms like [CitusDB](http://www.citusdata.com/) (Free up to 6 nodes) or [Vertica](http://www.vertica.com/about/) (Free up to 3 nodes) may also prove useful.